# Can you use Git Bash to remove folders/files from your computer?

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm new with Git Bash, but I've had some experience with it before. However, my sister has a folder/file on her USB that I can't seem to get rid of by right clicking and saying "delete" or by using "rm -r" or rm -f" on Git Bash. The folders in which I'm trying to delete with all its undeletable contents is called "Error" and I've tried to just say "Error" and put the path from the USB to the folder on "rm -r" and "rm -f" and it still won't delete. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score -1):

Please check the permissions on folder/files.  If the user attempting the deletion of the folder/file does not have the deletion permission, the user will not be able to delete the folder/file.

Comment: How do you check that?

Comment: Please look at this website:  https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/